# How do I put multiple SQL results into an array

Tags: php, arrays

I can not get my script to work and I do not understand why. I want to take all SQL results and put them into an array. My current script only returns a single result.

I know that I need to use a loop but I just don't know how to integrate it with the current script. I have read over 50 posts and I still cant get anything to work.

```
    <?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE sess_id = '$sess_id'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$count= mysqli_num_rows($result);      
$items= array();
    
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
  
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
    {  
    $items = "{sku: "."'".$row["prod_sku"]."'".", quantity : ".$row["prod_qty"]."}, <br>";
     }
                                              }
                                   }       
            echo $items."<br>";  
        ?>
```

Comment: It should be $items[] = ...

Comment: Btw, you don’t need num_rows; it doesn’t add any benefit, just another indentation.

Comment: @TimMorton Thanks for your comments. I added the []and it made no difference. I also removed the num_rows and it spat out an error. So I am still searching for an answer. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I honestly thought items should be an array since it’s in a foreach loop. Then I took a closer look and realized the foreach loop is meaningless; you don’t use $i  in the loop at all. All the foreach loop does is reassign $items over and over. At any rate, glad it helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is easy and simple and you do not need to use for loop inside the while loop. please use the following code, hope it would be helpful for you.

```php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE sess_id = '$sess_id'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);   
$items= array();

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $items[] = "{sku: "."'".$row["prod_sku"]."'".", quantity : ".$row["prod_qty"]."}, <br>";
    }
} 
// to print the array use the following command
// print_r($items);

// to echo the $items variable, you may encode it by json      
echo json_encode($items);
```

Thanks.

Comment: The world is a better place thank to people like you. My new issue is that when it diplays it looks like this;  
       ["{sku: 'sku_GKmZw6apqDvusM', quantity : 1},
","{sku: 'sku_GJ7qAnGTlFRwE8', quantity : 1},
"]
     Is there a way to get rid of the   "[    at each end?

Comment: the variale $items is a single array that you are wanted. you can use the $items by followings: foreach ($items as $key => $value) { echo $value;}

Comment: Thank you, that worked great. I tried using join and that too worked but now iit is not working in JavaScript. Could it be because the quantity is a string and not an integer? Here is the Javascript;
      
    stripe.redirectToCheckout({
        items:  [ <?php echo $items; ?>
        ],
         billingAddressCollection: 'required',
    successUrl: 'https://xxxxxie.com.au/success',
    cancelUrl: 'https://cxxxzzie.com.au/cancel',
  })

Comment: It is all fix now. This is how it looks now. 
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    $items[] = [
        'sku' => $row["prod_sku"], 
        'quantity' => (int)$row["prod_qty"]
    ];
}